# Influx of new users to ServerFault SE

Tags: discussion

Recently, I'm seeing a lot of messages from new users to serverfault.  Not commenting on the quality or applicability of the questions or content...I was just curious if this is something seasonal or a (good?) new trend.  Does SE contain any statistics on this type of activity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was caused by a change that Google made called [Panda](http://moz.com/google-algorithm-change) that has improved the discoverability of many SE sites. It happened in mid May 2014. You can see it's effect by going to [quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/serverfault.com) and selecting a suitable category and date range.